# Set min year in ngx bootstrap date picker

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'demo-datepicker-min-max',
  templateUrl: './min-max.component.html'
})
export class DemoDatepickerMinMaxComponent {
  minDate: Date;
  maxDate: Date;

  constructor() {
    this.minDate = new Date();
    this.maxDate = new Date();
    this.minDate.setDate(this.minDate.getDate() - 1);
    this.maxDate.setDate(this.maxDate.getDate() + 7);
  }
}
```

How to calculate year before 18 years and set min date to date before 18 years.
How to set minDate in ngx-bootstrap datepicker

```html
minDate = new Date();
minDate.setFullYear(this.minDate.getFullYear() - 18)
alert(minDate.setFullYear(this.minDate.getFullYear() - 18))
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to convert it back to a Date object. For instance,

```js
const currentDate = new Date();
const minDate = new Date(currentDate.setFullYear(currentDate.getFullYear() - 18)
);
console.log(minDate);
```

As for your the datepicker component, you will need to make use of the `minDate` input binding, and bind it to the property that contains the minimum date you want to set.

```
<input class="form-control"
       placeholder="Datepicker"
       ngModel
       bsDatepicker
       [minDate]="minDate"
       [maxDate]="maxDate">
```

On your component.ts,

```
this.minDate = new Date();
this.minDate.setFullYear(this.minDate.getFullYear() - 18);
```

I have forked a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ripj4g?file=app/ngx-bootstrap-demo.component.ts) for you. As you can see on the demo, you can't choose any years 18 years before the current year (2019).